# Need informations about RAID5 behaviour in XenServer 5.5

Tags: linux, raid, xen, boot

I've detected an I/O error in my partition /dev/sdd3 which is a part of 4 devices assembled with RAID5.

Now my server is in degraded mode with only 3/4 sync drives.
I have a boot partition (/dev/sdd1) that contains the XenServer, in order to replace the faulty disk (/dev/sdd) I need to have an other partition (a clone) of (/dev/sdd1).

The problem is: I cant boot from (/dev/sda1) event after copying the whole XenServer partition and changing (/boot/extlinux.conf & /etc/fstab).

I need to know what's the best way to choose:

1. Reparing /dev/sda1 and make it bootable to have a worked XenServer
2. Doing a new install in that partition (/dev/sda1) {can we still always reassemble the subsequent RAID5 array without loosing information?}

Need your help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this kind of problem, I've reinstalled my XenServer on all remained primary partition in my RAID5 array.

I want to say that every primary partition is not included in the Array, after copying all the necessary files using the command 
*cp -avf /source/* /destination*   .
I make that partiton bootable using the command 
*extlinux -i boot/*
Than I upgrade it with the install CD of XenServer5.5

After rebooting, I was able to find my RAID5 mounted as a Storage Repository automatically.

- So finally RAID5 will not be effected after an upgrade on a XenServer installation.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, no RAID on your boot devices?  Lesson for next time...

If you haven't installed a boot loader on the "new" boot disk, that'll cause you all sorts of grief.  I've never used extlinux (which is what it sounds like you're using) but I presume it has some sort of equivalent of `grub-install` or `lilo` that writes an actual boot sector.

If you do decide to do a new install into /dev/sda1, it should be possible to reconstruct the RAID-5 array from the remnants, but you may have to be very, *very* careful with the installer to make sure it doesn't take your instruction of "this is a RAID-5 array" as "this is a *new* RAID-5 array".  You might be better off not telling the installer about it at all and instead just assembling it by hand afterwards.

Comment: Thank you "womble",

I chrooted my disk (/dev/sda) to execute those command: 

# cat /usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin > /dev/sda
# cd /mnt
# extlinux -i boot/

when I boot from my (/dev/sda) disk I don't have any  Grub Error but I see the Xenserver (blue loading screen)  and it reboot with no success!